# Which Swing component for this design?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist

I am making a desktop application in Java and confused as to which swing component to use to achieve this result.

Here is the screenshot of the app.

[image]

I want to know the component for the content shown in the `JScrollPane`.

I am thinking of `JList` or `JTable` with Providing a Custom Renderer.
There will be alphabet headers and rows containing information.

Each row can be clicked to open a new window.
Row will also change its color on hovering.

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways

- JTreeTable (non_free Jide or SwingX)
- Accordion (implemented in [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/accordion-titledpane.htm))

Comment: Can these be customized according to my need as shown in image?
And can JavaFx components be used in Java Desktop applications?

Comment: there are a few  [good attempts in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10598227/2853553), but is about coding, you can to embeding JavaFx to Swing container (JavaFX2.2 and newer versios), but for mixing Swing v.s. JavaFx is better, have to wait for Java8 with JavaFX8

Answer (score 0):

You should go with JavaFX Accordion

[Titled Pane and Accordion](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/accordion-titledpane.htm)